# How can we restrict future date selection from tkCalender Date Entry picker in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am creating a graphic user application in Python using tkinter. For date picker I am using Date Entry from tkCalendar for this purpose. The requirement is to restrict user from selecting future dates. How can I achieve that in this case?

Python version 3.7

tkCalendar version 1.3.1

Comment: you are giving  potential answerer burden, post the code to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `set_date` method from `DateEntry` combined with `root.after()` to control the user input.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
time_now = datetime.now()
calendar = DateEntry(root, width=12, background='darkblue',foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
calendar.pack()

def date_check():
    calendar_date = datetime.strptime(calendar.get(),"%m/%d/%y")
    if calendar_date > time_now:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Selected date must not exceed current date")
        calendar.set_date(time_now)
    root.after(100,date_check)

root.after(100,date_check)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This isn't an ideal solution!! the best solution is to listen for changes on the widget itself. 

UPDATE!!!: For newer versions you can restrict the range using mindate and maxdate

Answer (score 4):

For tkcalendar >= 1.5.0 it is now possible to restrict the range of available dates with the `mindate` and `maxdate` options. So the following code prevent the user from selecting future dates:

```
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from datetime import date
import tkinter as tk
today = date.today()
root = tk.Tk()
d = DateEntry(root, maxdate=today)
d.pack()
root.mainloop()
```